# Remove space between the hidden elements and form submit

Tags: html, mysql, error-handling

I have a  form where user choose country according to which state and city selection box or textbox appears.

In country if `INDIA` is selected then it should populate selectbox with state and city selection otherwise textbox for city and state to write. I am able to implemeted that but there is two problem with it -

- first one is that when user select either of country there is space for the hidden part
- second form is submitted only for other countries that not for INDIA

what may be the problem in script and html? below is the code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadbox()
    {
    //var cnty=document.getElementById('country').slected;
    var x=document.getElementById("country1").selectedIndex;
    var y=document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
    if(y==22)
    {
    document.getElementById("selectbox").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("textbox4cnty").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("selectbox").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("textbox4cnty").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    }
    </script>
```

The html part

```
    <label for="country">COUNTRY</label>
<select id="country1" name="country1" onChange="loadbox()">         
<option value="" selected="selected" />SELECT</option>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM  `country` ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['country_id']; ?>">
<?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></option>
<?php                                            
  }
 ?>                                  
<option value="others">Others</option>
</select>         
<div id="selectbox" style="visibility:hidden">
<label for="State">STATE </label>
<select id="state1" name="state1"
onchange="getCity('select_city.php?state_id='+this.value)">
<option value="">SELECT</option>
<?php
$sql1="SELECT * FROM  `state`  ";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
 while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row1['state_id']; ?>">
<?php echo $row1['state_name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<label for="STREET">CITY </label>
<select id="city1" name="city1">
<option value="">select</option>
 </select> <br/>
<div>
<div id="textbox4cnty" style="visibility:hidden">
<label for="State">STATE </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="STATE" name="state1" required><br />
<label for="STREET">CITY </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="CITY" name="city1" required><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Use `display:none` instead of visibility

Comment: but it making no change on when selection is done that is remain invisible

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
if(y==22)

    {

    document.getElementById("selectbox").style.visibility = "visible";

    document.getElementById("textbox4cnty").style.visibility = "hidden";

    }

    else {

    document.getElementById("selectbox").style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.getElementById("textbox4cnty").style.visibility = "visible";

    }
```

**to**

```
if(y==22)

    {

    document.getElementById("selectbox").style.visibility = "visible";

    document.getElementById("textbox4cnty").style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.getElementById("selectbox").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("textbox4cnty").disabled=true;

    }

    else {

    document.getElementById("selectbox").style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.getElementById("textbox4cnty").style.visibility = "visible";

    document.getElementById("selectbox").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("textbox4cnty").disabled=false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has issues. You use a generic select of all options on the page

Here is how I would code it off the top of my head without digging very deep and keeping the inline event handler. It should be unobtrusive but one thing at a time

```
function loadbox(sel)     {
  var isIndia=sel.options[sel.selectedindex].text==="INDIA";
  document.getElementById("selectbox").style.display = (isIndia)?"":"none";
  document.getElementById("textbox4cnty").style.display = (isIndia)?"none":"";
  // and because you do not have ID on the second field names state1
  document.getElementsByName("state1")[0].disabled=!isIndia; 
  document.getElementsByName("state1")[1].disabled=isIndia;
  document.getElementsByName("city1")[0].disabled=isIndia;
}
```

using

```
<select id="country1" name="country1" onChange="loadbox(this)">
```

and

```
<div id="selectbox" style="display:none">
```

and

```
<div id="textbox4cnty" style="display:none">
```